# If a method takes a particular type of object as an argument, should it return a new instance of that object?

Tags: .net, refactoring

I'm trying to decide which of the two tests are structured the best to determine how Repository.SaveFoo(x) should be written.

```
//version 1
[TestMethod]
public void Saving_a_new_Foo_results_in_new_id()
{
    var x = new Foo { Id = 0 };
    x = Repository.SaveFoo(x); // Saves x and returns new Foo which is a copy of x but with an updated Id
    Assert.AreNotEqual(0, x.Id);
}

//version 2
[TestMethod]
public void Saving_a_new_Foo_results_in_new_id()
{
    var x = new Foo { Id = 0 };
    Repository.SaveFoo(x); // Saves x and updates x.Id
    Assert.AreNotEqual(0, x.Id);
}
```

I suppose the question could be rephrased as, should the SaveFoo method return a new object or simply update the object that was passed to it?

Note, I have simplified the code; the saving process results in properties other than the Id being changed also.

Answer (score 0):

`SaveFoo` should update the existing object, because that's the object that has been saved to the database.